# What are relevant CPC symbols for teaching methods?

Tags: process, method, education

I believe I have developed a novel method for teaching people how to think differently that is transformative at a deep and useful level. When I search for prior art, I get overwhelmed with devices and technical patents. I understand what I am operating in the utility and process/method area. What I think is novel is my approach to teaching.

I am wondering if there are general or specific CPC codes simply for new approaches to transformative instruction.

Comment: Have you reviewed the evolving standard for patentable subject matter?  Independent of classification code this may be considered abstract or a purely mental process.

Answer (score 1):

One application I found that is for a teaching method that does not involve a device is [US20080038700A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20080038700A1/) Method And System For Coaching Literacy Through Progressive Writing And Reading Iterations

It is classified under [G09B 19/00](https://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/defG09B.html#G09B19/00) "Teaching not covered by other main groups of this subclass".

Although there are no devices claimed, it was not rejected under section 101 as abstract when it was examined in about 2007 but as not novel in light of a previous patent document.

In whatever search tool you are using there is a way to have negative search terms. In google patent search you can have -device and -computer and -apparatus and -program to try to narrow a search. Narrowing to just looking at method claims will not help much becasue many methods require the use of some defined apparatus.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer and know little about CPC codes. That said, I searched Espacenet for CPC codes associated with "education" and the closed thing I found would be:

> G09B7/00: Electrically-operated teaching apparatus or devices working
> with questions and answers.

I don't know if this helps or even if your teaching method is even patentable.